# Sequelize: Sum value of nested column

Tags: sequelize.js

I'm trying to sum the value of a column in a nested hasMany relationship using sequelize v6. The following code is summing all nested rows not just those rows belonging to the parent record.

```
        const StockOrders = await models.StockOrder.findAndCountAll({
            limit: limit,
            offset: offset,
            order: [[orderBy, order]],
            include: [{
                model: models.StockOrderLine,
                attributes: [
                    [Sequelize.fn('SUM', Sequelize.col('StockOrderLines.calculatedItemQuantity')), 'itemQuantityTotal']
                ],    
                as: 'StockOrderLines'
            }],
            
        });
```

Can anybody please advise?

Answer (score 0):

To get the sum of a column from a joined table you should include it in the `attributes` of the root table. Since you don't need any of the row values from the joined table (via `include`) then you can omit them by passing in an empty array for the `attributes` value. I tend to order the config values based on the SQL parts they map to - select, join, where, order, group, offset, limit.

```js
    const StockOrders = await models.StockOrder.findAndCountAll({
        attributes: [
           // include the summed value here
           [Sequelize.fn('SUM', Sequelize.col('StockOrderLines.calculatedItemQuantity')), 'itemQuantityTotal']
        ],
        include: [{
            model: models.StockOrderLine,
            // don't include any columns here
            attributes: [],
            as: 'StockOrderLines'
        }],   
        order: [[orderBy, order]],
        offset: offset,
        limit: limit, 
    });
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Unfortunately it did not work. The SQL generated reads as


SELECT `StockOrder`.* FROM (SELECT `StockOrder`.`id`, SUM(`StockOrderLines`.`calculatedItemQuantity`) AS `itemQuantityTotal` FROM `StockOrders` AS `StockOrder` ORDER BY `StockOrder`.`id` ASC LIMIT 0, 10) AS `StockOrder` LEFT OUTER JOIN `StockOrderLines` AS `StockOrderLines` ON `StockOrder`.`id` = `StockOrderLines`.`stockOrderId` ORDER BY `StockOrder`.`id` ASC;


Maybe a sequelize verion issue... I shall post my solution below. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually managed to follow the advice on this page https://sequelize.org/master/manual/sub-queries.html

I had to use a partial raw query as follows:

```
        const StockOrders = await models.StockOrder.findAndCountAll({
            attributes: {
                include: [
                    [
                        // Note the wrapping parentheses in the call below!
                        Sequelize.literal(`(
                            SELECT SUM(calculatedItemQuantity)
                            FROM StockOrderLines AS StockOrderLines
                            WHERE
                            StockOrderLines.stockOrderId = StockOrder.id
                        )`),
                        'itemTotal'
                    ]
                ]
            },
            order: [[orderBy, order]],
            offset: offset,
            limit: limit
        });
```

That's all folks.